# How to use router url wildcard in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

I want to display my header component for every route that has **/admin** or routes that have these kind of urls **/admin/dashboard , /admin/users, /admin/tasks** or etc

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="page-wrap" class="inner-page {{router.url}}" *ngIf="router.url === '/admin'; else templateName">

  <app-header></app-header>

  <div class="page-content-wrap">

    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>

    <div class="content-wrap panel-right">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<ng-template #templateName>

  <div class="inner-page {{router.url}}">

    <div class="container">
        <flash-messages></flash-messages>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

  </div>

</ng-template>
```

But the code above only accepts /admin. Do you know how can I add a wildcard so that it accepts routes that have /admin/tasks, /admin/users ?

This is the condition that needs to be improved:

```
<div id="page-wrap" class="inner-page {{router.url}}" *ngIf="router.url === '/admin'; else templateName">
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can use `Child route` for all admin routes https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration

Comment: demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-child-routes?file=app/app-routing.module.ts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a method to check if the url is `/admin` or starts with `/admin/`:

```
isAdminRoute(value: string): boolean {
  return /^\/admin(\/|$)/.test(value);
}
```

and call it in the template:

```
<div *ngIf="isAdminRoute(router.url); else templateName" ...>
```

You can see the code at work in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhywej).

---

As an alternative, you could test the URL with the `startsWith` string method:

```
<div *ngIf="route.url === '/admin' || route.url.startsWith('/admin/'); else templateName" ... >
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I am trying to get your code to work

Comment: Thank you @ConnorsFan Worked like a charm